# Fetch json array in PostgreSQL procedure

Tags: json, postgresql, postman

I'm using PgSQL9.6.

I have procedure named as `createBooking` in PgSQL. It receive few parameters and one of them is `additional` type text.

Request is

`{ 
    "email": "user2@name.com",
    "start_date": "2016-10-21 11:00:00+00",
    "end_date": "2016-10-21 15:00:00+00",
    "guests": 50,
    "firstname": "User",
    "lastname": "Name",
    "payment_type": "Method 1",
    "phone": "+871253875123",
    "user_id": 22,
    "y_id": 3,
    "additionals": [
        {
            "extrasId": 6,
            "money": 19750,
            "packageId": null,
            "amount": 3
        },
        {
            "extrasId": 11,
            "money": 64380,
            "packageId": null,
            "amount": 5
        },
        {
            "extrasId": null,
            "money": null,
            "packageId": 3,
            "amount": 1
        }
    ]
}`

I'm trying fetch 'additioanl'.

`FOR i IN SELECT json_array_elements(createBooking.additional)
LOOP
    sum := sum + i->>'money';
END LOOP;`

It does not mater what is in body of loop. 
When I calling this function via PostMan it is sending me response with error.

`{
  "hint": "No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.",
  "details": null,
  "code": "42883",
  "message": "function json_array_elements(text) does not exist"
}`

Can some body explain me how should I fetch it?
Thank you.

Comment: Please post your `createBooking` procedure and way you call it.

Comment: The answer is in your error. The string you are passing in is type TEXT it needs to be type JSON to be parsed by a json function.